# Maven release prepare svn repository tags one form at a time?

Tags: svn, maven-release-plugin

In summary, I would like to archive under repository tags svn only the module or project that I modified (in the multi-module project), without reporting the other modules.

thank in advance

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're asking. "I would like to archive under repository tags svn only the module or project that I modified". Archive what? Are you trying to make a tag of a repository? What do you mean by "without reporting the other modules."? Can you be more specific for what you're trying to accomplish, what you've tried, and the results you're getting compared to the results that you'd like?

Comment: Sorry Chris. Let's say I have 30 projects (or modules) and I'm working on number 5 for example. I would like to archive on the repository in addition to the snapshot project under the root trunk, also the tag of the module only 5 under the root tags, without saving the other 29 modules that I have not touched.